# convert string from args[0] into char then populate and print a 2d array with the chars

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, char

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = args[0]; 

    String [] part = input.split(" "); 
    //splits string into 2 parts (action and characters to encode)
    String action = part[0];
    // action is what is done to letter i.e. decrypt or encrypt
    String plainText = part[0];
    char [] letters = plainText.toCharArray();
    //letters is the input of what to act on

        int n = plainText.length();
        //number of letters typed
        int boxsize; // overall size of box  
        boxsize = (int) Math.pow((Math.sqrt(n))+1,2);
        int Row = (int) Math.sqrt(boxsize); 
        int Col = Row;
        //length of rows AND columns since its square

    if (action.equals("-encrypt")) {

        char [][] box = new char[Row][Col];

        for (int i=0; i<Row; i++) {
        for ( int j=0; j<Col; j++) {

            System.out.println( i );
```

how do you populate a 2d char array if the argument is given as a string?
also how do you print the box (array) so that it reads vertically down each column left to right?\
an eg of command line would be "-encrypt abcd" (exclude quotation marks) 
output i want is "acbd"

Comment: and e.g. of args[0] would be the command line "-encrypt abcd" (exclude quotations marks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String plainText = part[1];
```

Was copied with 0

But generally without quotation marks args[0] would be the action, the rest args[>=1] spaced plainText.

Comment: how do you convert from string to char if e.g. the string is entered as an argument in command line (not using scanner) e.g. abcd how would you convert that to char?

Comment: The command line `java MyClass -encrypt acbd` would have `args[0] = "-encrypt"` and `args[1] = "acbd";`. And letters is still the array of chars. Assuming one does `String plainText = args[1];`