# how to convert string args[0] to char

Tags: java, string, char

How do you convert from string to char if, for example, the string is entered as an argument in command line (not using scanner). E.g. how would you convert `"abcd"` to char?

```
String input = args[0]
String [] part = input.split(""); 

//splits string into 2 parts (action and characters to encode)
String action = part[0];
// action is what is done to letter i.e. decrypt or encrypt
String plainText = part[1];
char [] letters = plainText.toCharArray();
```

Comment: Isn't this more or less the same question that you asked a little while ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942303/convert-string-from-args0-into-char-then-populate-and-print-a-2d-array-with-th

Comment: Yeah you asked the same thing 1 hour ago. Posting the same question multiple times doesn't help you finding the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a `String` with more than 2 characters to a `char` array:

```
String hello = "Hello";
char[] char_array = hello.toCharArray();
```

Otherwise if you only need one specific char, use `hello.charAt(0)`.

Please notice that you only can store one single 16bit Unicode character inside a `char` datatype. That's the reason why you need an array for more than 2 characters.